# XSLT newline not working in MS Build task

Tags: xml, xslt, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to transform an xml file to a textfile with MS Build [XslTransformationTask (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ff598688.aspx)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ff598688.aspx).

My problem is that I can only print new lines if I also combine them with other (non-space) text. So for example `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` does not produce a newline, but `<xsl:text>&#10;sampletext</xsl:text>` does.
I tried other variants like `<xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>` and `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` with same result.

MS Build Task:

```
<Target AfterTargets="Build" Name="Test">
<XslTransformation XslInputPath="config.xslt" XmlInputPaths="config.schema.xml" OutputPaths="out.txt" />
</Target>
```

XSLT doc:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='text' />

<xsl:template match="/root/properties">

<xsl:for-each select="./*">

<!--working new line character:-->
<xsl:text>&#10;name: </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />

<!--not working:-->
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<xml>
    <property>1</property>
    <property>2</property>
    <property>3</property>
</xml>
```

Sample XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='text' />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select='//property'>
        <xsl:if test='position() > 1 '><xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Creates

```
1
2
3
```